# Simple explanation of security issues related to input() vs raw_input()

Tags: python, security, input, built-in

I was reading this Python 2.7 tutorial and they're going over `raw_input()`, and it mentions that:

> The input() function will try to convert things you enter as if they
>   were Python code, but it has security problems so you should avoid it.

I tried Googling some explanations for this, but still a bit unclear to me; what's a simple explanation of the alleged inherent security issues with `input()` vs `raw_input()` ?

Comment: try creating an object as `a` and give it some input .Then use input() function to get user input from command line then just type `a` without quotes and print the value optained from user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `input()` function in Python 2.x evaluates things before returning.

So as an example you can take a look at this -

```
>>> input("Enter Something : ")
Enter Something : exit()
```

This would cause the program to exit (as it would evaluate exit()).

Another example -

```
>>> input("Enter something else :")
Enter something else :__import__("os").listdir('.')
['.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2', ...]
```

This would list out the contents of current directory , you can also use functions such as `os.chdir()` , `os.remove()` , `os.removedirs()` , `os.rmdir()`

Comment: Apparently this is no longer relevant as I can't reproduce it on python 3.7.2.